# Loop through database for a particular record and show results - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

i'm looking for a way to loop through the database and shows results in a html page, i'm actually creating a sorta fake email system for a little project.

so i have a table name "SENDS" with 5 columns ID, Mailtext, Touser, Subject, Fromuser.
what i wanna do is when user log in system connects to the database and select everything
from SENDS where touser='$email' -$email is defined when user logs in- and display it in a html div

```html
<div class="oubx">
  <div class="inbx">
   <span class="from"></span>
   <span class="subject"></span>
   <span class="mailtext"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```css
.oubx {
 height:27px; width:800px;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin-top:;
 margin-left:80px;
 float:left;
 background-color:white;
}

.inbx {
 height:22px; width:700px;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin-top:1px;
 margin-left:45px;
 background-color:white;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#808080;
 float:left;
}
```

from of course tells whos it from

subject is subject

mailtext is what the mail is (it's hidden of course jQ will take care of it once clicked)

i have used mysqli_num_rows, mysqli_fetch_array, for loops, foreach etc but i just can't seem to get my head around it i'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it setp by steps or what the step is. please help :) thanks.

```html
$connectDB = mysqli_connect("host","root","","db");

$touser = mysqli_query($connectDB, "select * from sends where touser='$email'");
$to_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($touser);
$to_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($touser);

//printing of html code = how many rows  
$ib = '<div class="oubx"><div class="inbx"><span class="from">'.$value.'</span><span class="subject">'.$value.'</span></div></div>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $to_numrows; $i++) {
 echo $ib;
}
```

the rest is work in progress..

Comment: hehey! Where is your server-side code? (PHP code to connect to database, fetch results, ...)

Comment: it's really bad i'm ashamed to put it here, having a bad day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$connectDB = mysqli_connect("host","root","","db");

$touser = mysqli_query($connectDB, "select * from sends where touser = '$email'");
$all_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($touser, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$ib = '';

foreach($all_rows as $row) {  
    $ib .= '<div class="oubx">'
         . '<div class="inbx">' 
         . '<span class="from">' . $row['Fromuser'] . '</span>'
         . '<span class="subject">' . $row['Subject'] . '</span>'
         . '</div>'
         . '</div>';
}

echo $ib;
```

**1-** `mysqli_fetch_all` will fetch all result row into a PHP array
**2-** We loop through it with foreach (no need to know the rows count)
**3-** Foreach row, we append the HTML to the `$ib` intially set to empty string.

Hope it helps.

Comment: brilliant, but it keeps giving me 
-Notice: Undefined index: Fromuser in C:\wamp\www\------\eifhfak_m.php on line 115-
-Notice: Undefined index: Subject in C:\wamp\www\------\eifhfak_m.php on line 116-

i wonder why is that, though code looks fine and i've tried using
isset().

Comment: @Aiden Well, what's the exact field name case?

Comment: @Aiden I have updated the answer (see the `mysql_fetch_all` statement).

Comment: @php_dev Awesome it works perfectly now though i tried it with 'MYSQLI_NUM' but now i know why it didn't work. In the mean time i came up with this:

`$query = "select fromuser,subject from sends where touser='$email'";
$result = $connectDB->query($query);

if ($result = mysqli_query($connectDB, $query)) {

    // fetch associative array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)<br>", $row[0], $row[1]);
    }

}`

This works pretty fine too, anyway thanks :) been a great help!!

Answer (score 0):

put the query result in a variable:

```
while ($row = $touser->fetch_array()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

and iterate it with a loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  /* show appropriate html here */
}
```